# Codename One: accessing localized string resources

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, codenameone, resourcebundle

I am porting my Android app to its cross-platform version (to have the iOS version) by means of Codename One.

I would like to use string resources like in the Android version.

I created a localization bundle (named "Localization (L10N) 1") only with english words for now.

In the main form I put this:

```
theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");
String lang= L10NManager.getInstance().getLanguage();
UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(theme.getL10N("Localization (L10N) 1",lang));
```

In another container class I have:

```
String StringRes(String id)
{
String result;
result=UIManager.getInstance().getBundle().get(id);
return result;
}
```

when I need a string, for example:

```
add(new Label(StringRes("title_string")));
```

I get null pointer error in StringRes method.

I know that it is just an attempt to manage string resources.

What is the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over thinking this... Codename One is localizable by default unlike any other framework I'm personally aware of.

Once you set the bundle value all you need to do is use the label with the right key e.g.:

```
add(new Label("title_string"));
```

It will "just work". Also you can use:

```
String value = getUIManager().localize("title_string", "This will show if title_string is missing from the bundle");
```

So `StringRes` isn't the right direction.

Comment: Excuse me, I would like to have something like in Android, for untranslatable strings. Your example seems to show that there is no fallback on "en" language when a string is not in the bunde. I almost sure there has to be a method similar to Android to manage untranslated strings. Am I wrong?

Comment: The second method allows you to do this manually and notice that the second parameter includes the fallback string. However, by convention this is far simplified in Codename One. Instead of using a meaningless string like "title_string" just use the actual value "My Title". Then `en` becomes the reasonable default which you have in the code and translation just becomes the process of changing an English phrase to another English phrase. There are some exceptions but they are pretty rare and can be handled using the second form of translation in my example

Comment: That sounds very strange to me. I cannot remember each string and each place I used it, usually the key has this purpose. And indeed strings can change many times during development. I did not understand. Maybe the strings will change in code in every occurrence if I change them in the bundle (sort of automatic refactoring)?

Comment: The bundle is in the resource file. You don't hardcode it. You can use an interface to include your strings in a single place if you would like to have it all in a single place for convenience. 
In the future we plan to introduce automatic bundling which will auto suggest strings when you run the simulator.

Comment: So the StringRes method is the right thing? Otherwise I think I did not understand. I want to use the keys, I understand that it just works if I put the strings but still I need to have a method that extracts the "en" strings, but I have that null pointer error.

Comment: The string res method you used just returns null if you didn't enter a string. It just looks in the map which is wrong. The localize method accepts a default fallback value in case the text is missing

Comment: I think that I have to extract the "en" strings from the bundle and then let Codename translate. Please can you tell me how to get the srings out of the keys? I want that the localizatioin bundle I have created is the source for the base strings, that is, the StringRes method has to work this way. But it is not working. I think that it is possible to query the bundle/map.

Comment: If you don't want automatic translation just don;'t set the bundle or use a bundle only with things you want to automatically translated. You can use the map from the resource file directly (which you extracted) if you wish to do so